# Style on ListView Contents is getting applied to the ListView itself

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I've encountered a strange behaviour in WPF/XAML. My intent is to create something like this, using `Border`s, a `ListView`, and a style for the `Border`s:

[image]

This is what I think the code should be:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20">
     <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
           <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
           <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
     </ListView.Resources>
     <Border/>
     <Border/>
  </ListView>
```

But that code actually produces this:

[image]

This lead me to play around a bit and I found something really strange. The `Width` and `Height` values in the Style for the `Border`s are getting applied to the `ListView` itself!

For example, this code:

```
 <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20">
     <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
           <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>//this should do nothing because the borders set their own height
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
     </ListView.Resources>
     <Border Height="20" Width="150"/>
     <Border Height="20" Width="150"/>
  </ListView>
```

Produces this:

[image]
(The height of the `ListView` is 100 pixels)

When I change the value of `Height` in the value of the Style, my expectation is that it applies to the `Border`s, who then ignore it because they set their own heights. In other words it should have no effect. But When I change `Height`, the height of the `ListView` changes.

To make things weirder, the `Background` value is properly being applied to the `Border`s. Do I have a misunderstanding about how this code should work? Have I found a bug? What is the right way to do what I am trying to do?

I am using Visual Studio 2022, .NET 6, C# 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. `ListView` uses a `Border` internally for its background. The Style is getting applied to this `Border`, as well as the `Border`s that are items in the `ListView`.

The solution is to use a type other than `Border`, or to make a user control that wraps `Border`. `Grid` works just fine:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20">
     <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
           <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
           <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
     </ListView.Resources>
     <Grid/>
     <Grid/>
  </ListView>
```

Produces this:

[image]